# Assigning reference type to non-reference type

Tags: c++, reference

Are both (1) and (2) correct ways to assign  the return type of a function when it is a reference to an objects? According to my compiler they are.

I know that in order to do
`<type> variable = someFunction();`
the return type of `someFunction` must be `<type>`.

So in the code below, following what I just said (1) is correct, since I am assigning a `const Bar&` return value to a `const Bar&`variable.

**How come (2) also works if the return type `const Bar&` and the  variable type `const Bar` are different. A  `&<type>` and a `<type>` are two different types, aren't they?** **What is the advantage or difference for using one or the other?**

```
class Foo {
       const Bar& FindBar(const int& num) const;
      string Foo_method(const int& num) const;

      {
        const Bar &bar_object = FindBar(num); //(1)
        //const Bar bar_object  = FindBar(num);  //(2)
        //do something with bar_object
        //return some string
       }

};
```

Comment: One is a reference, two is a copy.

Comment: Version `(2)` will invoke the `Bar(const Bar&)` copy constructor to create a local variable, `bar_object`. It will then return a reference to that local variable, except that reference will be dangling because `bar_object` will be destroyed immediately after `FindBar` returns. EDIT: I suppose the block of code isn't actually supposed to be the implementation of `FindBar` but an example of calling code. Point about the copy constructor remains valid.

Comment: @Nathan Pierson  iI edited the code , because I had made a mistake. I suppose you point is still valid.

Comment: @NathanPierson However I don't know where a reference to a local variable is being returned, are you sure? bar_object is a local variable in version (2) but  no reference to it is being returned

Comment: *"the return type of `someFunction` must be `<type>`."* -- close but not quite. After all, you could assign an `int` to a `float`, couldn't you?

Comment: @JaMiT, yes, so there is some kind of casting betwen <type> and &<type>?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO This conversion might fall under [lvalue to rvalue conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Lvalue_to_rvalue_conversion), but I sometimes get the technical nomenclature confused.

Comment: There's no return statements anywhere, my mind inserted a `return bar_object;` line when no such line is in your actual code. Anyway yes there absolutely is a conversion between `<type>` and `&<type>`, it's the canonical signature for the copy constructor.